# Create an Oracle Wallet to store DB Credentials on Windows

Tags: windows, oracle, ssl, credentials, wallet

I managed to create and store credentials in an oracle wallet on a Unix system using `mkstore` command line tool.

How can I achieve the same in Windows? Oracle Wallet manager seems to be a different thing that ask for certificate and certification authority and on command line `mkstore` give me syntax error ...

> 'The syntax of command is incorrect.'

I have run as administrator and have the Oracle Runtime Client 12.2 installed.

Any idea or help?

Comment: What is the syntax error you're receiving, and what is the full version number of the Oracle Client? There is a known issue with the mkstore.bat from version 12.2.0.1  - when you attempt to use it, it results in the error message: ''The syntax of command is incorrect.' Reverting to 12.1.0.2 fixes this. You can also try updating your ORACLE_HOME variable to the 12.2.0.1 folder to see if that has any impact. For anyone interested, this is Bug 26827996.


It would be helpful to include all error messages you receive so that we have a better idea about what the root cause might be.

Comment: The error is exactly the one you say ... I have the 12.2.0.1.0 so i have to reinstall totally to the other version? there is no way of changing only the bat file or something similar to fix this?

Comment: Posted an answer with a couple of different options that you may want to explore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a known issue with the mkstore.bat from version 12.2.0.1 - when you attempt to use it, it results in the error message: `The syntax of command is incorrect.` Here are a couple of possible options to get you going:

1. Revert to version 12.1.0.2.
2. Try updating your ORACLE_HOME environment variable to point to the 12.2.0.1 client to see if that has any impact.
3. Try copying the mkstore.bat from a 12.1.0.2 binary to replace your 12.2.0.1 version. Make sure to backup the previous .bat file.

For anyone interested, this is related to Bug 26827996. https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2406404.1

Comment: where can i find the binary of the mkstore.bat of the older version to substitute ?

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2.0) - https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/database12c-win64-download-2297732.html

Comment: ok but i have to install all the client or can i extrac only the bat file and substitute it?

Comment: Whichever is easier for you. You can just uncompress the zip and pull the bat, or just install the full client.

Comment: Option2 alone did magic for me. Thanks @1991DBA

Answer (score 2):

maybe this works for you too:
I've edit the file mkstore.bat and changed the following line

```
:check_orahome
if ("%ORACLE_HOME%") == () goto :no_orahome
```

to

```
:check_orahome
if ("%ORACLE_HOME%") == ("") goto :no_orahome
```

That helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue Syntax error every time I tried to do anything with mkstore.
Found that the person who built the server didn't set the ORACLE_HOME or TNS_ADMIN env variables but that didn't help. What did work was Markus F's suggestion to edit the mkstore.bat

:check_orahome
if ("%ORACLE_HOME%") == () goto :no_orahome
to

:check_orahome
if ("%ORACLE_HOME%") == ("") goto :no_orahome

Thanks very much Markus you saved me hours.

Comment: Your answer seems good, but can be improved if you format it right using the instructions beside the tab where you type the answer.